# Python axis name in plot

Tags: python, plot, axes

can I change a location for signature for axis? like write them on end of axis? and instead of them write another inscription? 
Now I have 
[image]

In code this inscriptions I set

```
plt.plot(dataX, dataY)
plt.xlabel('f, Hz')
plt.ylabel('N')
plt.savefig(pathForNewGraphDir + "\\" + shortFileName + "_" + str(i) + "_.png")
```

But I need [image]

thank you

Comment: Have you tried text annotations?

Comment: If you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148149/annotate-a-plot-using-matplotlib, that's not actually what I need..

Comment: You can change the location of the axis label, but I doubt you can put two labels in two different locations. As @Aleksander mentioned, check out text annotations, you should be able to put a text outside the canvas.