# Matplotlib showing error while try to use annotate() method?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot views by post (vbyp list) using matplotlib.plt() 
and using a names list to add text at each point. But, the annotate function keeps show the error :

```
x, y = xytext
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

To rectify it I have used the `range()` method but it doesn't correct it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

names = ['S','Deuk','Cip','Pubt','Adoct','Vsa','Rener',
'Gols','OYO','Qum','Sre','Mey','Micft',
'Nia','Tco','Texments','Fidty','Jrgan','Adoch','MyKa','Dw','Ba','HL','Nx','Towerch','Uer']
posts = [6,3,4,4,6,3,3,8,7,2,15,4,5,5,2,2,2,5,3,2,2,3,4,1,1,1]
views =[554,1272,257,197,545,170,162,18465,419,107,931,1140,438,15626,72,104,219,336,217,1527,278,122,252,56,62,62]
vbyp = []
for i in range(len(posts)):
    vbyp.append(views[i]/posts[i])
plt.plot(vbyp)
for i in range(len(vbyp)):
    plt.annotate(names[i],vbyp[i])
plt.show()
```

Without annotation I get an image like :
[image]

But I want something like this :[image]

Comment: You need to use `annotate` correctly. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148149/annotate-a-plot-using-matplotlib) is an example for you

Comment: To position an element on a plane you need two coordinates, usually called x and y. You need to supply those two coordinates as a tuple or list to the `annotate`'s `xy` argument. Here you only supply a single number.

Comment: Also, could you tell us where exactly are to trying to put the names? Do you want them as x-tick labels on the x-axis? I think what you want is `plt.annotate(names[i],(i, vbyp[i]))`

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @KartikeySingh: Glad to help. You are welcome

Comment: What is the reason behind using i in `plt.annotate(names[i],(i, vbyp[i]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities to relate your names with the corresponding values. You will have to choose for your own whichever you like the best.

First: using your method correctly which gives not so good plot. In `annotate`, you have to specify your string `names[i]` and an (x,y) coordinate for which you were just providing a single number so far.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,5))    

# Your code here
for i in range(len(vbyp)):
    plt.annotate(names[i],(i, vbyp[i]))
```

**Output**

[image]

Second : Using names as x-tick labels which generates much better and readable plot.

```
plt.xticks(range(25), names, rotation=45)
```

**Output**

[image]